# iPhone connect textfield end on exit event to button press event

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have a text field and a button.  When the button is pressed, it calls a routine.  I want the textfield end on exit to call the same routine without having to duplicate the code.  ViewController.h is below

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityind;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *search;

- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ViewController.h implement UITextFieldDelegate like so:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and then use the method

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

and call your IBAction and resignFirstResponder, I would also auto-enable return key.

Comment: In viewcontroller.m?  If so, I already have that, see below:

- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    // hide keyboard
    [search resignFirstResponder];
    

    NSString *query2 = [search.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mathcelebrity.com/namesearch.php?searchInput=%@", query2]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    NSTimer *timer;
}

Comment: The calculate is the button press event.  I'm looking to have that same routine called if somebody presses enter in the uitextfield named search without pressing the calculate button

Comment: Outstanding!  The only change I made was to move [search resignFirstRepsonder] to the doSomeWork routine so that we only need to do that once.  It works now, thanks for helping me link up the actions to the routine, that is one thing I've wanted to learn as I'm coming from 6 years of .php and this is my third week doing these apps.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT1]**

In your viewController header:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityind;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *search;

-(void)doSomeWork;
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;

@end
```

Simply implement the functionality in a 2nd tier routine.

In your viewController.m file:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(search == textField){
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self doSomeWork];
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)doSomeWork{
    // Do whatever you want to do here!!!
}

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
    [self doSomeWork];
}
```

In your xib file you will have to connect up the button to the "calculate" action, the search to the proper UITextField.

You can set the delegate of the UITextField either graphically in the Interface Builder, or in code.  If in code, then within your viewController.m file add the line:

```
search.delegate = self;
```

to your viewDidLoad method as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    search.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: That piece with the function works, however, for the text field, am I making that an action, or just a regular textField with no action?

When I do the textField with an action, it does not let me use "search" as an accessor.  When I do the text field with no action, but as an outlet, I can access it, but I don't know how to call the function from there.